# Exclude posts in a category on one page but show those posts on a different page

Tags: posts, categories

We have a lot of blog post categories, and posts belonging to all but one category should show on the blog page. The other category should show on the `Case Studies` page.

The solutions I've found make a global exclusion using `functions.php`, which would break the `Case Studies` sort.

I'm comfortable working with PHP but not sure how I would go about excluding the category on just one page.

Edit: Here is an example of category exclusion that I think would globally exclude category with ID of 1
in `functions.php:`

```
function exclude_category($query) {
    $query->set('cat','-1');
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','exclude_category');
```

Below is one that is specific to a `feed` page. Does it know to exclude it on the `feed` page because `feed` is the slug of the page to exclude for?

```
function exclude_category($query) {
    if ($query->is_feed) {
        $query->set('cat','-1');
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','exclude_category');
```

Comment: Hello & welcome :) May you edit your question and post the code you used for the global exclusion, please? I think it will help you find answers faster when people see what you have tried already and why it is not working. Also, do you have a specific template in place for the Case Studies category (for example, `category-case-studies.php`) or are you using the default `category.php` or `archive.php` or falling back on `index.php`?

Comment: Yes please add the code you are looking at to exclude the one category.  It likely needs a condition applied to limit the impact.  The preferred way to approach this is filtering the main query with a function hooked to `pre_get_posts`.

Comment: Thank you both. I edited the question with the code i found. I do not have a specific template, I actually have not used or overridden custom templates but would like to learn how. I see I can select a template to use in "Page Attributes" but do not know where to create a new template file to be selected there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by creating a custom page template for my Blog page to exclude posts of the category `Case Studies`.

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/) more or less and was successful adding the category exclusion code in my original post to exclude the case studies.